# Unique Validation Angular when edit

Tags: angular, validation

I am using the same form to create and edit. It works well; The problem I have is that when I edit in a field where I have a unique validation, it shows me the validation and doesn't let me save the changes. How could I solve this. My form is the following:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGDsY.jpg)

add-edit-beneficiario.ts

```
 import { Component, OnInit, } from '@angular/core';
import { AutoIdentificacion } from '../autoidentificacion';
import { Genero } from '../genero';
import { AbstractControl, AsyncValidatorFn, FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, ValidationErrors, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { MyErrorStateMatcher, errorMessages } from '../my-error-state-matcher';
import { AutoidentificacionService } from '../services/autoidentificacion.service';
import { GeneroService } from '../services/genero.service';
import { CantonService } from '../services/canton.service';
import { ParroquiaService } from '../services/parroquia.service';
import { AsentamientoService } from '../services/asentamiento.service';
import { ProvinciaService } from '../services/provincia.service';
import { Provincia } from '../provincia';
import { Canton } from '../canton';
import { Parroquia } from '../parroquia';
import { Asentamiento } from '../asentamiento';
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { BeneficiarioService } from '../services/beneficiario.service';
import { Beneficiario } from '../beneficiario';
import {  timer, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import {  map, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators'; 
import { CedulaValidator } from '../unique-cedula-validator.directive';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-edit-beneficiario',
  templateUrl: './add-edit-beneficiario.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-edit-beneficiario.component.css']
})
export class AddEditBeneficiarioComponent implements OnInit {
  beneficiario: boolean=false;
  autoidentificaciones: AutoIdentificacion[];
  id: number;
  isAddMode: boolean;
  generos: Genero[];
  provincias: Provincia[];
  cantones: Canton[];
  parroquias: Parroquia[];
  asentamientos: Asentamiento[];
  selectedAutoIdent:any;
  selectedGenero:any;
  selectedCanton:any;
  
  public addEditBeneficiarioForm: FormGroup;
  matcher = new MyErrorStateMatcher();
  errors = errorMessages;

  public formErrors={

    cedula:'',
    nombres:'',
    autoident:'',
    genero:'',
    canton:'',
    parroquia:'',
    uuidasentamiento:'',
    
  }

  constructor(

    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private autoidentService: AutoidentificacionService,
    private generoService: GeneroService,
    private provinciaService:ProvinciaService,
    private cantonService: CantonService,
    private parroqService: ParroquiaService,
    private asentService: AsentamientoService,
    private benefService: BeneficiarioService,
    

  ){
    
  this.beneficiario=false;
  
  }
  // -----CONTROL PARA VALIDAR LAS CEDULAS DE FORMA UNICA
  cedula = new FormControl('',{
      
    validators: [Validators.required,Validators.minLength(10),Validators.maxLength(10)],
    asyncValidators: [this.benefService.uniqueCedulaValidator() ],
 
  
  });
 
  ngOnInit(): void {
   
    this.createForm();
    this.autoidentService.obtenerListaDeAutoIdentificacion().subscribe(autoident=>autoident=autoident);
    this.provinciaService.getProvincias().subscribe(provincias=>this.provincias=provincias);
    this.autoidentService.obtenerListaDeAutoIdentificacion().subscribe(autoidentificaciones=>this.autoidentificaciones=autoidentificaciones);
    this.generoService.obtenerListaDeGeneros().subscribe(generos=>this.generos=generos);
  }

  hasError(field: string, error: string): boolean {
   
    if (error === 'any' || error === '') {
      return (
        this.addEditBeneficiarioForm.controls[field].dirty &&
        this.addEditBeneficiarioForm.controls[field].invalid
      );
    }
   
    return (
      this.addEditBeneficiarioForm.controls[field].dirty &&
      this.addEditBeneficiarioForm.controls[field].hasError(error)
     
    );
    
  }

  private createForm(){

    this.addEditBeneficiarioForm = this.fb.group({
      
      id: [''],
      cedula:this.cedula,
      nombres:['', Validators.required],
      fecnacimiento:['', Validators.required],
      x:['', Validators.required],
      y:['', Validators.required],
      idautoident: ['', Validators.required],
      genero: ['', Validators.required],
      provincia:['',Validators.required],
      canton: ['', Validators.required],
      parroquia: ['', Validators.required],
      uuidasentamiento: ['', Validators.required],

    });

  }

 




  onChangeProvincia(provId){
   // console.log("Valor de la prov seleccionada es "+provId.dpa_despro);
    
   

    if(provId){
      this.provinciaService.getCantonesByProvincia(provId.dpa_provin).subscribe(data=>this.cantones=data)
    }

  }

  onChangeCanton(canId){
  
    if(canId){
      this.provinciaService.getParroquiaByCanton(canId.dpa_canton).subscribe(data=>this.parroquias=data)
    }
  }

  onChangeParroquia(parId){
   
    if(parId){
    this.provinciaService.getAsentamientoByParroquia(parId.dpa_parroq).subscribe(data=>this.asentamientos=data)
    }
  }

  
  compareAutoIdent(o1: any, o2: any):boolean{

    return o1.descripcion === o2.descripcion && o1.id === o2.id;

  }
  
  compareGenero(o1: any, o2: any):boolean{

    return o1.descripcion === o2.descripcion && o1.id === o2.id;

  }

  compareProvincia(o1: any, o2:any):boolean{
    
    return o1.dpa_despro === 'ORELLANA' && o1.dpa_provin === 22;
  }
  compareCanton(o1: any, o2:any):boolean{
    return o1.dpa_descan === o2.dpa_descan && o1.dpa_canton === o2.dpa_canton;
  }

  compareParroq(o1: any, o2: any):boolean{
   
    return o1.dpa_despar === o2.dpa_despar && o1.dpa_parroq === o2.dpa_parroq;
  }

  compareAsent(o1: any, o2: any):boolean{
   
    return o1.nam === o2.nam && o1.uuidasentamiento === o2.uuidasentamiento;
  }

  compareObjects(o1: any, o2: any):boolean{
    
    return o1.descripcion === o2.descripcion && o1.idautoident === o2.idautoident;
  }

}
```

add-edit-beneficiario.html

```
<mat-card-content>

<form [formGroup]="addEditBeneficiarioForm"
       (ngSubmit)="addEditBeneficiarioForm"
       [class.error]="!addEditBeneficiarioForm.valid && addEditBeneficiarioForm.touched" class="col s12">

<mat-form-field appearance="outline"  > 

    <mat-label>Cédula</mat-label>
    <input matInput [formControl]="cedula" name="cedula" 
      formControlName="cedula"   [errorStateMatcher]="matcher" required type="cedula">
          <mat-error *ngIf="addEditBeneficiarioForm.controls['cedula'].errors?.maxlength || addEditBeneficiarioForm.controls['cedula'].errors?.minlength"  >La cédula debe tener  10 caracteres</mat-error>
          
          <mat-error *ngIf="addEditBeneficiarioForm.controls['cedula'].errors?.required">{{errors.required}}</mat-error>
          <mat-error *ngIf="cedula.errors?.existeCedula">
            La cédula ya existe
          </mat-error>
  
</mat-form-field>
<br>
<mat-form-field appearance="outline"> 

    <mat-label>Nombres</mat-label>
    <input matInput  formControlName="nombres" id="nombres"  [errorStateMatcher]="matcher" required >
          <mat-error>{{errors.required}}</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
<br>
<mat-form-field appearance="outline"> 

    <mat-label>Fecha de nacimiento</mat-label>
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" formControlName="fecnacimiento" id="fecnacimiento" [errorStateMatcher]="matcher" required>
            <mat-hint>MM/DD/YYYY</mat-hint>
            <mat-datepicker-toggle matIconSuffix [for]="picker">
              <mat-icon matDatepickerToggleIcon>keyboard_arrow_down</mat-icon>
            </mat-datepicker-toggle>
            <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
            <mat-error>{{errors.required}}</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
<br>

<mat-form-field appearance="outline"> 

  <mat-label>Coordenada X</mat-label>
  <input matInput type="number" formControlName="x" id="x"  [errorStateMatcher]="matcher" required >
        <mat-error>{{errors.required}}</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
<br>
<mat-form-field appearance="outline"> 

  <mat-label>Coordenada Y</mat-label>
  <input matInput type="number" formControlName="y" id="y"  [errorStateMatcher]="matcher" required >
        <mat-error>{{errors.required}}</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
<br>
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
  <mat-label>Género</mat-label>
  <mat-select [compareWith]="compareObjects" [(ngModel)]="selectedGenero"  formControlName="genero" id="genero" >
  
    <mat-option *ngFor="let gen of generos" [value]="gen">
    {{gen.descripcion}}
   </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
  <mat-error >{{errors.required}}</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
<br />
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
  <mat-label>Autoidentificación</mat-label>
  <mat-select [compareWith]="compareObjects" [(ngModel)]="selectedAutoIdent"  formControlName="idautoident" id="idautoident" >
  
    <mat-option *ngFor="let aut of autoidentificaciones" [value]="aut">
    {{aut.descripcion}}
   </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
  <mat-error >{{errors.required}}</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
<br />
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
  <mat-label for="Provincias">Provincia</mat-label>
  <mat-select formControlName="provincia" [compareWith]="compareProvincia"   (ngModelChange)="onChangeProvincia($event)" >
    <mat-option [value]="null">Seleccione una provincia</mat-option>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let prov of provincias" [value]="prov">
      {{prov.dpa_despro}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
 
</mat-form-field>

<br />
          <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
            <mat-label for="Cantones">Cantón</mat-label>
            <mat-select  formControlName="canton" [compareWith]="compareCanton" 
            (ngModelChange)="onChangeCanton($event)" >
              <mat-option [value]="null">Seleccione un cantón</mat-option>
              <mat-option *ngFor="let can of cantones" [value]="can">
              {{can.dpa_descan}}
             </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
          </mat-form-field>  

          <br />
          <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
            <mat-label>Parroquia</mat-label>
            <mat-select formControlName="parroquia" [compareWith]="compareParroq"  id="parroquia" 
            (ngModelChange)="onChangeParroquia($event)">
              <mat-option>
              
              </mat-option>
              <mat-option *ngFor="let par of parroquias" [value]="par">
              {{par.dpa_despar}}
             </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
            <mat-error >{{errors.required}}</mat-error>
          </mat-form-field><br />

          <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
            <mat-label>Comunidad</mat-label>
            <mat-select formControlName="uuidasentamiento"  [compareWith]="compareAsent"  id="uuidasentamiento">
              <mat-option *ngFor="let ase of asentamientos" [value]="ase">
              {{ase.nam}}
             </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
            <mat-error >{{errors.required}}</mat-error>
          </mat-form-field><br />
</form>

</mat-card-content>
```

Validator code

```
uniqueCedulaValidator(): AsyncValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): Observable<ValidationErrors | null> => {
      if(!control.value){
        return of(null);
    }
    return this.existeCedula(control.value).pipe(
      map((existeCedula) => (existeCedula ? {existeCedula: true } : null) ),
      
      );
     
    };
  }
```

beneficiario.service.ts

```
 import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
 import { Beneficiario } from '../beneficiario';
 import { Observable, Subscriber, delay } from "rxjs";
 import { AbstractControl, AsyncValidatorFn, ValidationErrors } from '@angular/forms';
    import { catchError, map, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
    import { of } from 'rxjs';
    import { transformMenu } from '@angular/material/menu';
    import {  timer } from 'rxjs';
    
    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class BeneficiarioService {
     
     
      private RutaAPIrest ="http://localhost:8090/beneficiario";  
    
      httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        })
      }
    
      constructor(private httpclient : HttpClient, private beneficiario:Beneficiario) { }
    
      doSomething(): Observable<Beneficiario[]>{
    
        return this.obtenerListaDeBeneficiarios();
    
      }
    
      //------OBTENER LISTA DE BENFICIARIOS---------
    
      obtenerListaDeBeneficiarios():Observable<Beneficiario[]>{
    
        return this.httpclient.get<Beneficiario[]>(`${this.RutaAPIrest}`)
    
      }
    
      //-------OBTENER BENEFICIARIO POR CEDULA
    
      getBeneficiarioByCedula(cedula:string):Observable<Beneficiario>{
        return this.httpclient.get<Beneficiario>(`${this.RutaAPIrest}/filterbycedula?cedula=${cedula}`)
      }
    
      //----------VERIFICA SI EXISTE LA CEDULA--------------
    
      existeCedula(value: string):Observable<{existeCedula:boolean}>{
    
       return this.httpclient.post<{existeCedula: boolean}>(`${this.RutaAPIrest}/filterbycedula?cedula=${value}`,JSON.stringify(value),this.httpOptions);
            }
    }
```

Comment: What does “unique validation “ mean?

Comment: I am using an asynchronous validator to validate the ID of a beneficiary and prevent duplicate IDs from being entered. The registry works but when I want to edit this validator it won't let me save the changes

Comment: Could you please add the code of your validator and code of form initialization?

Comment: this.existeCedula is not defined in your example, so what looks like the _actual_ validation logic is still missing. Can you add that as well?

Comment: I have added the code of the existCedula method. This method calls the api on the backend and returns true if the cedula exists.